# How can I count the number of configuration files in /etc directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I want to count configuration files in `/etc` directory and to count all the files including link files in `/etc` directory

This is what I have tried

```
ls -l /etc | grep ?conf | wc -l
```

Comment: This is what you have tried … where is your result different from your expectations? (my assumption: `'?conf'` is either an invalid regex, or depending on flavor a regex matching the literal `?` – you probably meant `conf$` or `.conf`, `.` matching any character)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to find all config files recursively:

```
find /etc -name '*conf' | wc -l
```

(Assuming no config file will have a line break in its name.)

Whether or not you want to exclude directories and how you want to follow symbolic links, you need to slightly adapt this command:

```
find /etc -not -type d -name '*conf' | wc -l
find -L /etc -name '*conf' | wc -l
find /etc \( -type f -o -type l \) -name '*conf' | wc -l
```

---

If you don't want to find files matching the name pattern recursively, you can specify the global `-maxdepth 1` option:

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name '*conf' | wc -l
```

*or* use `ls` with a switch to not print the contents of directories (but this will include directories itself in the count, which might or might not be what you want):

```
ls -1bd /etc | grep 'conf$' | wc -l
```

`-b` replaces non-graphic characters with C-style escapes, so you should even be safe if your filenames contain newline characters.

Comment: You could have a directory called `somethingconf`, need to add `-not -type f`.

Comment: @root Directories are files too ;) but yes, very valid point. I've adapted my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't want to find recursively.

Comment: @JigmeWangdi I've updated my answer. Recursive or non-recursive is an important detail which should already be specified in the question :)